# Как изменить путь к корню сайта?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

Как изменить путь к корню сайта?

Проблема такая.

Обычно на локальном сервере, если ввести в строку браузера localhost/ то начнется загружаться файл index.php, который лежит в корне сайта, например localhost/www/index.php.
А мне надо, чтобы при вводе localhost/ файл index.php искался в папке public (localhost/www/public/index.php).

Так вот как и где изменить путь к корню сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В конфигах апача находите пункт DocumentRoot, напротив этой директивы прописан путь, меняете его на свой.